# Is the migration statistics page currently broken?

Tags: bug, migration, statistics

I had some idle thoughts about question migration statistics, but the [migration statistics page for Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) is currently ... impoverished.

[image: Information-free statistics summary]

I recall a breakdown by source and destination site: "10 questions migrated to Math (3 rejected); 3 questions migrated to Engineering (1 rejected)" and so on. Is this something peculiar about my setup, or has the page changed intentionally, or is it just temporarily missing the information I remember, or have I dreamed the whole thing?

Another user in Teacher's Lounge confirms similar behavior on a larger SE site:

[image]